# Removing outliers in data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, outliers, threshold

i'm trying to remove some values from this data set that I have as a txt. file. I couldn't really figure out how to do it, so my teacher said that I could do something likes this, so that the colums with a Z value at 9.9999.. I could just remove. But it does not seem to work. I want to remove all the data that exceed the threshold +/- 1500.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
from astropy.io import ascii
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pandas as pd
from astropy.table import Table

#Data from KIC 1864183

df = ascii.read(r'G:\Downloads\kplr001864183_kasoc-ts_llc_v1.dat')

x_Julian_data = df['col1']

x_data_raw = (x_Julian_data-54000)*86400 #Julian time to seconds: 60*60*24
data = np.linspace(0, 65546, num = int(65546) , endpoint = True)
y_data_raw = df['col2'] #Relative flux ppm

for i in range (65546-2):#Cleaning up data
    data[i+1] = y_data_raw[i+1]-.5*(y_data_raw[i]+y_data_raw[i+2])
    data[i+1] = abs(data[i+1])-1500#Used to filter out data spikes accosiated w/ noise
    data[i+1] = abs(data[i+1])+data[i+1]
    data[i+1] = (data[i+1]/(data[i+1]+1E-9))*9.9999999999999
    
data[0] = 0
data[65545] = 0


mmy = y_data_raw.mean() #Mean y value

mmx = x_data_raw.mean() #Mean x data

x_data = x_data_raw-mmx

y_data = y_data_raw-mmy

# Simple plot
plt.figure('KIC 1864183')
plt.title('Relative flux vs time (KIC 1864183)', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Relative flux (ppm)')
plt.plot(x_data_raw, y_data, 'r')

# Creating file
file = Table()
file['x'] = x_data
file['y'] = y_data[enter image description here][1]
file['z'] = abs(data)
ascii.write(file, 'values_1864183.2.dat', overwrite=True)
print(file)
```

Comment: Are you asking how best to process your data, or do you know what you want to do but not how to implement it in Python? I really don't understand what the sequence of operations in your `for` loop is supposed to be doing - I suggest you write out the mathematical formula for the transformation you want to do, then ask if you can't figure out how to do that in Python. Do you want to *remove* the data points that you decide are outliers, or just filter the data so it is less noisy? Lastly, you can remove the code from `# Simple plot` onwards - it isn't relevant to what you are asking.

Comment: I want to help you, but you need to describe better the component of your problem. For instance, "so that the colums with a Z value at 9.9999.. I could just remove", are you sure you want to remove the whole column?! Also, when you say "But it does not seem to work." what so you mean about that? Clarify. Lastly, "I want to remove all the data that exceed (...)" what do you mean as "all the data" here? As @nekomatic said, narrow down your question to what you really need and struggle with; define your problem properly.